# Set Disabled Background and Text Color in RichEdit Control in Delphi

Tags: delphi, background-color, richedit, textcolor, disabled-control

I have developed a custom component derived from a richedit component.

I used the example in PBExEdit created by Peter Below to erase and repaint the background. This is successful in having a different color for the richedit background when disabled. However, the text that is in the richedit is not repainted. I have attempted to use the following lines to no success. The component does not even render on run.

```
procedure WMPaint...
var Format: TCharFormat2;
begin

//call to erase and paint bg using WMEraseBkGnd...
//Here are the lines that are not working.
  try
    FillChar(Format, SizeOf(Format), 0);
    Format.cbSize := SizeOf(Format);
    Format.dwMask := CFM_COLOR;
    Format.crTextColor := ColorToRGB(Font.Color);
    Perform(EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_ALL, LongInt(@Format));
  end;

end;
```

I also tried the EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR and that did not work.

I think there is more required to the EM_SETCHARFORMAT... but I am at a loss.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Barry